# Docker Image - Skipping project, because it was not found

Tags: dockerfile

[My Project directory view is in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHvSa.png)

When I am trying to create image for **Srv.OAuth** project by keeping the Dockerfile in the main directory of this project getting the following error:

> Skipping project "/Lib.Communication/Lib.Communication.csproj" because it was not found.
>   Skipping project "/Lib.Database/Lib.Database.csproj" because it was not found.

**Docker Command :**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY Libraries/Lib.Database.csproj ./
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Srv.OAuth.dll"]
```

**Output of the execution :**

> D:\xxx\xyz\abc\Srv.OAuth>docker image build -f Dockerfile -t almsoauth .
>   Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.016MB
>   Step 1/10 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
>    ---> b23b0e275fcd
>   Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
>    ---> Running in a0b396e6b4be
>   Removing intermediate container a0b396e6b4be
>    ---> 43a54eff5619
>   Step 3/10 : COPY *.csproj ./                                                                                             ---> 0cb2208057f7
>   Step 4/10 : RUN dotnet restore                                                                                           ---> Running in a9ab75a03390                                                                                             Skipping project "/Lib.Communication/Lib.Communication.csproj" because it was not found.
>     Skipping project "/Lib.Database/Lib.Database.csproj" because it was not found.